# making available just some parts of theme option

Tags: custom-post-types, child-theme, theme-options

I'm just starting to understand and learn about how Wordpress works. Now i'm trying to build a simple website (6 pages, gallery, slideshow) by using a downloaded from wordpress.org. The theme that I'm using has slideshow support in `Theme Options` section, but I'll like to hide the fact that i'm using that theme, or to replicate its functionality.

I'm thinking that maybe I can add a custom post type, but I'm too new to wp and I'm scared. Also, I was thinking that I can use some plugins like `members` in order to block some users access to the themes, but to allow access only to theme options section. With this plugin I can only hide access to entire Appearance section.

I'm looking forward for your advice.

ps: I don't know if it really matters or not, but the theme that I'm using is `thbusiness`.

Comment: It seems like you're actually asking three questions here; it's likely your question will be put on hold because of this. Why do you need to add a custom post type? If you're interested in learning how to develop for WP you can skip the plugin for members and instead read the [WP Codex entry on user roles and capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities); this will let you limit who has access to the theme options pretty easily.

Comment: @Dre ty for the link. Please make it as an answer in order to mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're actually asking three questions here; it's likely your question will be put on hold because of this. Why do you need to add a custom post type?

If you're interested in learning how to develop for WP you can skip the plugin for members and instead read the [WP Codex entry on user roles and capabilities;](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) this will let you limit who has access to the theme options pretty easily.

I had a quick peek at the theme files and it looks like it's using the [Options Framework](http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/) to add its options. If you look inside `options.php` you'll see that `$options` consists of a multi-dimensional array. The Options Framework is pretty easy to use; simply include the necessary files and then create your options as required.